# Adding to a gridview with custom adapter

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I want to dynamicaly add custom views to a gridview using a custom adapter inheriting BaseAdapter, the custom view i'm using inherits from RelativeLayout and has two TextViews as children.

Comment: Please could you be more explicit, give us some of your first tests ?

Comment: post your code man